# TypeError: PageMethods.hypothesis_save is not a function

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have stuck in this code for a week can somebody tells what it's wrong with my code.

I have a popup with button using jquery ui dialog. 
Note that:
I have load script manager and enable page method in my master page.

1. My .aspx file:

```html
<div id="Input_Hypothesis" style="display: none">

    <form name="form1" method="post">
        Please select distribution type
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li data-tab="tabs-1"><a href="#tabs-1">Normal</a></li>
                <li data-tab="tabs-2"><a href="#tabs-2">Lognormal</a></li>
                <li data-tab="tabs-3"><a href="#tabs-3">Weibull</a></li>
                <li data-tab="tabs-4"><a href="#tabs-4">Exponent</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--my tab info is here -->
            <asp:Button id="BtnNormal" runat="server" Text="NormalKe" Enabled="True" onClientclick ="return NormalBtn();"/>
            <asp:Button id="BtnLogNormal" runat="server" Text="Lognormal" Enabled="True" />
            <asp:Button id="BtnWeibull" runat="server" Text="Weibull" Enabled="True" />
            <asp:Button id="BtnExp" runat="server" Text="Exponent" Enabled="True"  />
            <br />
        </div>
```

2. this is my javascript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function NormalBtn() {   
        var data = $("#data").val()
        var id = <%=id%>;
        //var dist = <%--= dist--%>;

        PageMethods.hypothesis_save(id, data, result);
    };

    function result() {
        location = '../Stage1/data_analysis.aspx?stage=2&id=<%=id%>&tab=1&h='+$("#data").val();
    };
</script>
```

3. This is my function in code behind:

```vb
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub hypothesis_save(ByVal data As String, ByVal id As String)
    Try
        Dim type As String = ""
        Dim dist = "normal"
        If (data.Contains("cr")) Then
            type = "cr"
        ElseIf (data.Contains("depth")) Then
            type = "depth"
        ElseIf (data.Contains("length")) Then
            type = "length"
        End If

        Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString)
        sqlcon.Open()

        Dim query As String = "select count(*) from s2_prob where ass_id =" + id + " and type = " + type
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, sqlcon)

        Dim jum As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        If (jum > 0) Then
            query = "update s2_prob set histogram = '" + data + "' where ass_id =" + id
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Else
            query = "insert into s2_prob(histogram,ass_id) values('" + data + "', " + id + ")"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

---

Thanks in advance. I really need to figure it out as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you have any other working PageMethods? If you debug your javascript in the browser dev tools does PageMethods exist and does it have your function?

Comment: yes i have other working PageMethods function and its work fine. When debug it cannot find my hypothesis_save function. Any ideas?